# draw jquery line chart to the database values

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, charts

I have some values in database, this values will  be keep changing as per the program is written. Now my question is how do i retrieve the values and display it as a line chart using jquery?

Comment: did you try anything so far?

Comment: yeah i searched so much. iwas told that i need to use jason and all so i am confused and i put my question here since i dont know jason

Comment: are you using any chart creation plugin for that ???

Comment: what is your issue , getting value from DB using jquery OR displaying those values in the chart ??

Comment: displaying those values in chart

Comment: currently dont have any idea on that since for the first time i am working on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jqplot for this. In order to get the values from database you can use json, which is best suited for your requirement.